# How to reuse results of substitution in both dependency name and target body?

Tags: makefile

I am trying to use SECONDEXPANSION feature https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion
to dynamically select dependencies. So far I have the following fragment of code. However, I want to avoid duplication when defining expression `$(word 4, $(subst -, , $@))`.

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:


mydep-4v1:
    echo 4v1


mydep-4v2:
    echo 4v2


foo-%: mydep-$$(word 4, $$(subst -, , $$@))
    X=$(word 4, $(subst -, , $@)) && \
    echo foo: $$X
```

```
make foo-a-b-4v1-c-d # foo: 4v1
make foo-2-3-4v1-5-6 # foo: 4v1
make foo-a-b-4v2-c-d # foo: 4v2
make foo-2-3-4v2-5-6 # foo: 4v2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no opinions on the "rightness" of this, but it's trivial to do what you want.  Just put the expression into a variable:

```
get-word = $(word 4, $(subst -, , $@))

foo-%: mydep-$$(get-word)
        X='$(get-word)' && echo foo: $$X
```

Since you escape the call of `$(get-word)` in the prerequisite list it won't be expanded until secondary expansion.  Of course you could also use:

```
foo-%: mydep-$$(get-word)
        X='$(patsubst mydep-%,%,$<)' && echo foo: $$X
```

Or do it all in the shell as John suggests.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to use SECONDEXPANSION feature [...] to dynamically select dependencies.

That's usually a bad idea IMO.  Of course, I tend to frown on most other GNU `make` extensions, too.

> So far I have the following fragment of code. However, I want to avoid duplication when defining expression $(word 4, $(subst -, , $@)).

Even those who are more accepting of GNU extensions than I am should generally avoid calling `make` functions inside recipes.  It's almost always better to use shell features instead.  In this particular case, you already have the result you want as part of the prerequisite name, and you can use  `make` automatic variables to access that, so perhaps you're looking for something like this:

```
foo-%: mydep-$$(word 4, $$(subst -, , $$@))
    X='$<'; \
    echo foo: "$${X#mydep-}"
```